# Image using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Using `Rails 2.3.15` and `paperclip 2.3.0`

It is easy to display image as follows:
i.e.

```
@product.img_url.url
```

Now, I have join on two tables and from the result of the join I want to fetch and show the image.

e.g.

```
   @searchItems = Product.find(:all, :select => "p.id, p.title, p.img_url, p.img_url_file_name, p.img_url_content_type, p.img_url_file_size, p.url, pp.selling_price",
                              :conditions => "p.category = 'Mobiles'",
                              :joins      => "as p inner join product_pricings as pp on p.id = pp.product_id")
```

`searchItems` is an `array`.
How do I get image from the `array`, like I get from model.

Any help would help me lot.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't

```
@searchItems.each do |product|
  do_something_with(product.img_url.url)
end
```

what you mean?